# Возникла проблема с npm пакетом react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

я подключил react-redux и возникла такая проблема, работал с connect -ом.Помогите понять что за проблема пожалуйста.Спасибо
https://github.com/Martin-front-git/react-test
[image: TypeError]
[image: index.js]
[image: container]

Comment: ./store/redux-store.js что в этом файле?

Comment: Могло бы быть из-за циклических зависимостей, но вроде не похоже. Используй отладчик.